# How to set several values for a Flurry Analytics parameter?

Tags: flurry, flurry-analytics

According to [Flurry Analytics Events FAQ](http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=Analytics/FAQ/Events):

> ... Each event can have up to 10 parameters, and each parameter can have any number of values.

Is it possible to set multiple values for a single Flurry Custom Event Parameter **at once**?

Example use case:

- Event: User opens an article

  - Parameter Name: **hashtags**
  - Parameter Value: **a list of tags this article is tagged with**

As a result, I want to see top 10 most popular tags in the Parameters pie chart on Flurry dashboard.

Thank you!